# How can get a converted number to a string and add characters to the end of that string if a checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript

have been trying to get a field with a number converted to a string them add characters to the end of that converted string if a checkbox is checked.
The deal is that the field value may or may not start off as number or a string.
I'm trying to do that with embedded if statements.
I can't get this to work.

```js
function validatesendNewFixedCust(){

var checkboxIfNewInstallment = document.getElementById("checkboxIfNewInstallment").checked;

var NOTAPROVEDOR = document.getElementById("NOTAPROVEDOR").value.toString();
var stringCaracter = " | ";


if(checkboxIfNewInstallment == true){
alert("checked")
     if(!NOTAPROVEDOR.includes(" | "))
       {NOTAPROVEDOR + " | 1"}

//do something

}
if(checkboxIfNewInstallment == false){
alert("checkBox not checked")
//do something
}


}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>

  </head>
  <body>

<input type="checkbox"  id="checkboxIfNewInstallment" name="checkboxIfNewInstallment" />

<input id="NOTAPROVEDOR" value="12455" type="text" >

<input type="button" class="buttonBlack"  id="sendNewFixedCustBtn" value="OK" onclick="validatesendNewFixedCust()"       >
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You do not need `toString()` on line 3 as `value` alredy returns a string.

Comment: Try like this `if(!NOTAPROVEDOR.includes(" | ")) { document.getElementById("NOTAPROVEDOR").value = NOTAPROVEDOR + " | 1"; }`

Comment: This worked for me thank you! Karan.

Answer (score 0):

There was a bit of adjustments to your code. Take a look

```
function validatesendNewFixedCust() {

  var checkboxIfNewInstallment = document.getElementById("checkboxIfNewInstallment").checked;

  var NOTAPROVEDOR = document.getElementById("NOTAPROVEDOR").value.toString();
  var stringCaracter = " | ";


  if (checkboxIfNewInstallment == true) {
    alert("checked")
    if (NOTAPROVEDOR.indexOf("|") == -1) {
      //updated the below line
      NOTAPROVEDOR += " | 1"
    }
    //updated the below line
    document.getElementById("NOTAPROVEDOR").value = NOTAPROVEDOR;
    

  }
  if (checkboxIfNewInstallment == false) {
    alert("checkBox not checked")
    //do something
  }


}
```

And your HTML code is untouched. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code. You can assign value to the inputs using

```
document.getElementById("NOTAPROVEDOR").value = NOTAPROVEDOR + " | 1";
```

And merged two if condition to a single one like

```
if(!!checkboxIfNewInstallment && !NOTAPROVEDOR.includes(" | "))
```

```js
function validatesendNewFixedCust(){
var checkboxIfNewInstallment = document.getElementById("checkboxIfNewInstallment").checked;
var NOTAPROVEDOR = document.getElementById("NOTAPROVEDOR").value;
if(!!checkboxIfNewInstallment && !NOTAPROVEDOR.includes(" | ")) {
  document.getElementById("NOTAPROVEDOR").value = NOTAPROVEDOR + " | 1";
  console.log("checked");
} else {
  console.log("Not checked or text contains '|'");
}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
<input type="checkbox"  id="checkboxIfNewInstallment" name="checkboxIfNewInstallment" />
<input id="NOTAPROVEDOR" value="12455" type="text" >
<input type="button" class="buttonBlack"  id="sendNewFixedCustBtn" value="OK" onclick="validatesendNewFixedCust()">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: All of the suggestions here have worked, I wish I could select multiple answers as the correct ones. But yours has dramatically simplified the code.  I particularly like the double `!!` in the statement logic, that's new to me.